# Efficient way of finding repeating sequences of characters in string

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to do the following:

1. Read file contents into byte array
2. convert byte array into Base64 String
3. find all sequences of repeating characters that are longer than 8 in length
4. place the found repeating patterns in a list

Here is where I am currently having some issues... I am currently reading a 1MB file using this loop:

```
void bkg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(this.txt_Filename.Text);
        string file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        char lastchar = '\0';
        int count = 0;
        List<RepeatingPattern> patterns = new List<RepeatingPattern>();


        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            this.pb_Progress.Maximum = file.Length;
            this.pb_Progress.Value = 0;
            this.lbl_Progress.Text = "Progress: Read file contents read... Looking for patterns! 0% Done...";
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.pb_Progress.Value += 1;
                this.lbl_Progress.Text = "Progress: Looking for patterns! " + (int)Decimal.Truncate((decimal)((double)i / file.Length) * 100) + "% Done...";
            });

            if (file[i] == lastchar)
                count += 1;
            else
            {
                //create a pattern, if the count is more than what a pattern's compressed pattern looks like to save space... 8 chars
                //[$a,#$]
                if (count > 8)
                {
                    //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                    RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar, count);
                    if (!patterns.Contains(ptn))
                        patterns.Add(ptn);
                }
                count = 0;
                lastchar = file[i];
            }
        }
        e.Result = patterns;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        e.Result = ex;
    }
}
```

However, when using this loop, I find that the process is VERY long... for example, this 1MB file, takes like 1 minute to loop through... in this day in age, it feels like this is a long time for such a small file. Is there a more efficient way to do what I want to do/find the repeating patterns?

Comment: Did you check what's taking such a long time? I mean, the loop itself seems efficient enough, did you make sure it's not the `ReadAllBytes` or the `ToBase64String` that's taking most of the time?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes... this is all done in a seperate thread and I am updating the UI at key phases (before read + convert, then after read and convert is done, for example), and those two steps/things are very fast... maybe a millisecond for `ReadAllBytes` + `ToBase64String` ... it is really the looping through the chars that is taking a long time... i find anyway.

Comment: aren't there any algorythms or something to go through this faster? feels like i'm just not using the right loop or something? >>

Comment: This whole procedure took `58ms` in my machine, using a `5Mb` text file. No patterns were added though, because you expect sequences of exactly 8 chars. Maybe you should show the missing *threaded* section.

Comment: How many repeating patterns is it finding? There may be ways to allocate less if it's a large percentage of the input file but as others have pointed out, the loop itself is fine.

Comment: @Jimi keep in mind that this is not a text file... it can be any type of file... it reads the bytes, then converts the bytes into a string, then parses the string char by char... a 1.09MB file for me (a .exe file, although the content type should not matter), takes about 1 minute to parse through using my loop above, in Debug mode, in VS 2017...

Comment: Bytes are bytes. Are you actually getting any pattern? Is your `RepeatingPattern` doing something when it gets a new one? How are threads involved, here? What threads? Are you updating a ProgressBar of sort?

Comment: weird... it is the UI updating part that seems to be taking a while... I have some MethodInvoker calls in my loop to update a label and progress bar during the process... when I remove those, the loop is almost instant?? Maybe this is the wrong question to ask then?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question :) For example, if you used `Invoke`, change it in `BeginInvoke()`. Don't check `.InvokeRequired`. But you have to post the thread-related code. Possibly, use the [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) Interface.

Comment: @Jimi I have updated the code to include the full set that is within the BackgroundWorker doWork :) Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Never, ever, `Invoke()` from the `DoWork` event (or the `OnDoWork` method). Use the [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged) (raised asynchronously in the UI Thread) event to update the UI. Anyway, I suggest to run a Task and use the aforementioned `IProgress<T>` interface to perform the update (it won't change much in this scenario, though, but it's a good *exercise*).

Comment: @Jimi so I was unable to find a "progress reporting" structure that did not tie up the UI or require too much processing times in order to report the progress itself... so I've decided to simply not report the progress to the user... I find this sad... is there not some way to do this without going from 10ms to 1 minute?? Or am I simply looking at changing my progress report for "less steps" in order to have less UI calls?

Comment: Yes, that's what's usually done (you could inspect the ,Net source code to see how some reporting events - such as the WebClient's `DownloadProgressChanged` event - determine when *it's time* to report an update). You know the file size in advance. Divide its size in `100` chunks,  so you report progress each `1%` of the file size (i.e., don't report progress on each byte read). Raise the `ProgressChanged` event when you have read the calculated amount of bytes, set the progress = 100 when done reading (using the `RunWorkerCompleted` event) - if there are no errors - and all will be fine.

Comment: @Jimi Ok sounds good and that is what I did and it remains super fast! I divided it up in like 6 or 7 steps. ;) You can post your answer and I will accept it :)